# How do I deploy my react app to GitHub Pages in production mode?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

So, I created a basic React App following a tutorial so I could use it as my new GitHub homepage.  When I run npm locally it shows me my React App as pictured below.  However when I go to my GitHub Pages address (https://robagruen.github.io/), I get the second image pictured.  I've looked around online, and I'm having trouble figuring out what's going on with this.  I have run both `npm run build` and `npm run deploy` and the script runs leaving the output message of "Published." however this does not seem to be the case to me.  I've also added `"predeploy": "npm run build"` and `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"` to my package.json file.  Has anyone else run into this before with GitHub pages?  I'd really appreciate any helpful advice!  Thank you.

[image: Local version of my react app]
[image: Github Pages version of the react app]

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to deploy in the GitHub user page:

```
https://yourUserName.github.io/
```

As opposed to a Project Page:

```
https://yourUserName.github.io/yourRepo
```

You need slightly different steps:

Create a new copy of your Master branch, (you can name it as you like):

```
$ git checkout -b source
$ git push origin source
```

This way the source branch is a direct copy of our master.
Next steps:

1. Navigate to your repo on Github, and select "Settings".
2. On the left-side panel, click on "Branches".

[Figure: Changing the default Branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utrYu.png)

Then you will be able to select the 'Source' branch and update it.
Now in the terminal (source branch) run:

3. yarn deploy

Wait a couple of minutes, refresh and you be able to see your site at:

```
  https://yourGitUser.github.io/
```

Making changes:

Your source branch is acting like your master. So for next changes, merge your changes into source.

You might find more information about this on the following article:
https://dev.to/javascripterika/deploy-a-react-app-as-a-github-user-page-with-yarn-3fka

Note, if your next project you deploy a project page, you might follow the steps described here:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom

Answer (score 1):

After following this tutorial, https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-deploy-your-react-application-to-github-pages-in-less-than-5-minutes-8c5f665a2d2a ,make the changes in packages.json

Then, create a branch named **gh-pages** and push it to the github with the same branch name **gh-pages**. Then change the source to ***gh-pages branch*** in Github Pages section in settings

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this is the issue because I have never deployed to github pages but it looks like the url for the page should be formatted as so:

http://{username}.github.io/{repo-name}

According to this resource https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `master` branch for the Github pages feature and that's why is showing the README file as the main page.

Set the default branch to `gh-pages` in the repository settings **or** change the deployed React source to `master`.

Answer (score 0):

change deploy script from `"gh-pages -d build"` for `"gh-pages -b master -d build"`.

This is only needed for personal websites [username].github.io.